# How do I get Windows SFTP (OpenSSH) users a unique directory for that user

Tags: openssh, sftp, windows-server-2019

I have a Windows 2019 server set up with OpenSSH version 7.7:

```
$ ssh -V

    OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
```

I want to give each user their own directory; I have a user [`fti`] and want them to use:

```
D:\inetpub\ftproot\LDNClient\Import\fti
```

- Within `sshd_config` I have:

  ```
  Subsystem   sftp    internal-sftp
  ...
  Match User fti
  ChrootDirectory d:\inetpub\ftproot\ldnclient\Import\fti
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  X11Forwarding no    
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  ```

  - I've tried putting `ChrootDirectory d:\inetpub\ftproot\ldnclient\Import\fti` *before* `Match User fti`, and it works to transfers files, however that won't work overall because I have other users that need their own directories

Excluding the above bullet, when opening Filezilla, I see directory `c:\users\fti`. I'm restarting OpenSSH with every config change, directory does exist, has full permissions, and is owned by `fti`; there is no directory specified in the user properties using Computer Management.

What have I got wrong?

Comment: Check what you're doing against the two answers in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1579157/openssh-windows-multiple-directories-for-different-users).

Comment: Both links the same, I have everything in thiem showing.  Match user in lower case, ChrootDirectory pointing to proper place, owned by the user.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to a different subsystem command that pointed to the sftp-server.exe in the windows directory like:

```
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe -d C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH
```

After making that change, everything worked for fti as well as other users.